# How can i change the value of param 'items'<c:forEach var="entity" items="${p:someSortByTime(someEntities)}">to replace the way of sorting

Tags: jsp, jstl, tomcat8, java-ee-6, jstl-functions

I have such snippet of code, I would like to change the way of sorting (now is sortByTime) but for instance i want to change for sortByTitle or sortById how can i do this?

Exist class with my methods of sorting enity (**omitting for brevity some methods**)

```
public final class ListEntitySort {

    private static Comparator<Entity> compareByStartTime = Comparator.comparing(Entity::time);

    public static List<Event> sortByTime(List<Event> events) {
        events.sort(compareByStartTime);
        return events;
    }
... more 
}
```

FOR this sort I use function.tld

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
        version="2.1">

    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>Entity_Functions</short-name>
    <uri>ua.com.example</uri>

    <function>
        <name>sortByTime</name>
        <function-class>ua.com.example.web.command.functions.ListEntitySort</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.util.List sortByTime(java.util.List)</function-signature>
    </function>
  
    <function>
        <name>formatLocalDateTime</name>
        <function-class>ua.com.example.web.command.functions.Dates</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.String formatLocalDateTime(java.time.LocalDateTime, java.lang.String)
        </function-signature>
    </function>

</taglib>
```

in serlvet I obtain and set attribute

```
 List<Entity> entities = someService.getListEntities();
 request.setAttribute("entities", entities);
```

```
 <c:forEach var="entity" items="${p:sortByTime(entities)}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${entity.id}</td>
                    <td>${entity.title}</td>
                    <td>${entity.description}</td>
                    <td>${entity.location}</td>
                    <td>${p:formatLocalDateTime(entity.time, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')}</td>
                    <td>
 </tr>
```

Probably create a flag that will send the sorting method to the servlet and change the sorting method parameter in for each.
or maybe add scriplet in jsp<% %>
or in jsp make something with if tag via jstl

```
<c:if test="${check the way of sorting }">
put here for each
</c:if>
```